# Как может быть реализован редирект(?) для файлов изображений без указания расширения в apache?

Tags: apache, redirect, httpd

Достался по наследству старый сервер с FreeBSD c Apache 1.3.37. 
Там лежит сайт, который вполне работает. Но тут появилась задача перенести сайт на новый сервер.
Сайт незамысловатый и в общем-то проблем с переносом почти не возникло.
Однако, столкнулся со странным поведением Apach'а, которое никак не смог объяснить.
При запросе типа [http://домен/путь/картинка](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), он без проблем отдаёт браузеру эту самую картинку. Вот только такого файла в файловой системе нет. Зато есть, например, картинка.gif. Или картинка.png. (jpg, jpeg...)
Первое, что пришло в голову - это RewriteRule, но нет - никаких правил там нет ни в .htaccess, ни в самом конфиге Apache.
В связи с этим вопрос к знатокам: каким таким волшебным образом подобное можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам на собственный вопрос.
Оказывается есть такая опция в апаче **MultiViews**, поставляется в модуле **mod_negotiation**, которая как раз и позволяет получать файл, даже если запрос содержит только имя файла без расширения.
Т.е. при запросе **filename**, и если файла такого файла на самом деле нет, апач выдаёт первый попавшийся файл по маске **filename.*** .
Мне кажется, это не безопасно как-то.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
...
        <Directory /srv/www/path/to/project/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>
```